# Using dictionary.ContainsValue with tuple as the value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a dictionary where I am storing a key and 2 values in a tuple like so:

```
variableDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
```

So my dictionary is: `key, <value1, value2>`

I want to check if a value1 is already stored in the dictionary. If my dictionary was string for the key and string for the value I could just use [ContainsValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
bool alreadyStored = variableDictionary.ContainsValue(value1);
```

I'm not sure how to find whether my *value1* is in the dictionary in the *value1* part of the tuple regardless of what the *value2* is. I could create a new tuple and check whether it contains this tuple but I'm not sure how to make it effectively ignore the second value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ContainsValue` performs simple linear search](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs#0c84534e1447d1de#references), so you can do the same with LINQ pretty easily:

```
bool alreadyStored = variableDictionary.Any(x => x.Value.Item1 == value1);
```